# How to make hidden-to-hidden weight matrix in recurrent neural net fixed and not trainable in lasagne?

Tags: theano, lasagne

In Lasagne, [Layer](http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/base.html#lasagne.layers.Layer) class has field `params` which, according to the documentation, stores all registered parameters along with their tags in the ordered dictionary. However, for the layer of the type [RecurrentLayer](http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/recurrent.html#lasagne.layers.RecurrentLayer) input-to-hidden and hidden-to-hidden weight matrices are absent in `params`. Why is that so?

Initially, I wanted to keep the values of the hidden-to-hidden matrix fixed, in other words, make `hidden_to_hidden.W` not trainable. It can be done for parameters in `params` dict by removing the `trainable` tag.